# Monitoring http errors from tomcat with Grafana

Tags: java, http, tomcat, grafana

I need to create a dashboard to monitor all http erros that thrown by my rest api application. My application uses embedded spring-boot tomcat and I don't know how to retrieve thoses metrics.

If anyone know a solution, please, help-me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to integrate a monitoring system like [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)
and then you can use Grafana to create dashboards having promotheues as a datasource